# There is no function $f$ on the open unit disk, defined by a convergent power series, such that $f(1/n)=(-1)^n/n^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Prove that there is no function $f$ on the open unit disk, defined by a convergent power series, such that $f(1/n)=(-1)^n/n^2$.

I'm not sure how to start... any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $g(z) = z^2$ and look at points where $f(z) = g(z)$.

Comment: From here how can we conclude that there is no holomorphic/entire fuction $f$ ? Please reply